# Populating a field with the count of another field

Tags: database, gis, one-to-many, arcgis, arcgis-online

I preformed a one to many join with a buildings layer (one) and a table of internal cameras (many). This produced a table with multiple records per building.

Now, I would like to label the buildings based on the number of cameras joined to a building. For example, a building with 8 cameras would be labeled 8.

How would I to populate a field with the number of cameras in each building?
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'Summary statistics' geoprocessing tool on your internal cameras table to generate a count per some unique id that exists in your building table.  Then you can join and calculate the result back to your building table.